# Heroku deployment of plotly-dash application - build failed

Tags: python, heroku, plotly-dash

I've built a plotly-dash application which runs fine on my local machine, but I cannot get it deployed correctly via Heroku. You can find my [code here](https://github.com/GDRomaine/COVID-19-Vax-Dash/tree/main). I've been following the [Heroku for Sharing Public Dash apps for Free](https://dash.plotly.com/deployment) documentation instructions. Everything is fine until I run `git push heroku master`. I receive the following error:

> `remote:        ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.20.0 (from -r /tmp/build_4c17f53a/requirements.txt (line 19)) (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0b3, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.11.1rc1, 1.11.1, 1.11.2rc1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0b1, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.1rc1, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5) remote:        ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.20.0 (from -r /tmp/build_4c17f53a/requirements.txt (line 19)) remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.`

I thought maybe I wasn't re-installing the right dependencies. After activating the virtual environment. I run `pip install dash`, `pip install plotly`, `pip install kaggle`, `pip install pandas`, and finally `pip install gunicorn`. I've also tried `pip install numpy` and many other libraries I thought were unnecessary, to no avail however.

I've tried editing `requirements.txt` so that `numpy==1.19.5` and that actually allows the push to go through. But then there is some application error once I try to open the app on Heroku. Any help would be much appreciated!